# Join print output to variable

Tags: python, regex

So I got this working... and it prints out what is expected. I need to now store the print output into a variable. Any pointers/ideas on how to clean this up?

```
re1='(Tag)' # Word 1
re2='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re3='((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))'  # Alphanum 1
re4='(.)'   # Any Single Character 1
re5='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))' # Word 2

rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    var1=m.group(1)
    alphanum1=m.group(2)
    c1=m.group(3)
    word1=m.group(4)
    print ""+""+alphanum1+""+""+c1+""+""+word1+""+"\n"
```

Comment: instead of print, use a variab;le.

Comment: `out_var =  ""+""+alphanum1+""+""+c1+""+""+word1+""+"\n"`?

Comment: Put it into a variable instead of printing it...?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of things that may be of use:

- `re.VERBOSE` flag (same as `re.X`) ignores whitespace and comments. This makes it easier to document your expression.
- `(?P<name>expr)`: returns `{"name": "expr"}` in `match.groupdict()`. This makes it easier to use the results.
- `str.format` will accept named variables, ie `"{this}".format(this = 5)`
- you can use the `**dict` operator to unpack a dict to named variables.

Put these together and you get:

```
reg = re.compile(
    """
        (?P<word1>tag)                       # word1
        .*?                                  #
        (?P<alphanum>[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)  # alphanum
        (?P<ch>.)                            # ch
        (?P<word2>[a-z]{2,})                 # word2
    """,
    re.I | re.S | re.X
)

m = reg.search(txt)
if m:
    s = "{alphanum}{ch}{word2}".format(**m.groupdict())
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringIO to capture all output.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
backup = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StringIO() 
... your code  ...
val = sys.stdout.getvalue()
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = backup
```

your output will be in `val`